# How to generate pandas dataframe timedelta column grouped by id and date (YYYY-MM-DD)?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timedelta

Suppose I have a dataframe with `id` and `datetime` columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["a1", "a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a2", "a3", "a3", "a3", "a3"],
                   "datetime": ["2016-01-01 00:01:00.156",
                                "2016-01-01 12:00:00.425",
                                "2016-01-02 00:59:00.123",
                                "2016-01-02 14:16:00.548",
                                "2016-01-01 12:00:00.147",
                                "2016-01-01 13:59:00.123",
                                "2016-01-02 08:01:00.147",
                                "2016-01-02 18:49:00.123",
                                "2016-02-01 12:00:00.147",
                                "2016-02-01 13:59:00.123",
                                "2016-02-02 08:01:00.147",
                                "2016-02-02 18:49:00.123"]})
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df
```

Here is the dataframe:

```
    id  datetime
0   a1  2016-01-01 00:01:00.156
1   a1  2016-01-01 12:00:00.425
2   a1  2016-01-02 00:59:00.123
3   a1  2016-01-02 14:16:00.548
4   a2  2016-01-01 12:00:00.147
5   a2  2016-01-01 13:59:00.123
6   a2  2016-01-02 08:01:00.147
7   a2  2016-01-02 18:49:00.123
8   a3  2016-02-01 12:00:00.147
9   a3  2016-02-01 13:59:00.123
10  a3  2016-02-02 08:01:00.147
11  a3  2016-02-02 18:49:00.123
```

I want to generate column `timedelta` that has a timedelta value. This is the output I expect to get:

```
    id  datetime                datetime_baseline       timedelta
0   a1  2016-01-01 00:01:00.156 2016-01-01 00:01:00.156 0
1   a1  2016-01-01 12:00:00.425 2016-01-01 00:01:00.156 719
2   a1  2016-01-02 00:59:00.123 2016-01-02 00:59:00.123 0
3   a1  2016-01-02 14:16:00.548 2016-01-02 00:59:00.123 797
4   a2  2016-01-01 12:00:00.147 2016-01-01 12:00:00.147 0
5   a2  2016-01-01 13:59:00.123 2016-01-01 12:00:00.147 119
6   a2  2016-01-02 08:01:00.147 2016-01-02 08:01:00.147 0
7   a2  2016-01-02 18:49:00.123 2016-01-02 08:01:00.147 648
8   a3  2016-02-01 12:00:00.147 2016-02-01 12:00:00.147 0
9   a3  2016-02-01 13:59:00.123 2016-02-01 12:00:00.147 119
10  a3  2016-02-02 08:01:00.147 2016-02-02 08:01:00.147 0
11  a3  2016-02-02 18:49:00.123 2016-02-02 08:01:00.147 648
```

Here is how the `timedelta` values should be calculated: 1) the code needs to identify the FIRST datetime within the same `id` and date ('YYYY-MM-DD'), and 2) use it as baseline (`datetime_baseline`) to compute the timedelta (in minutes) w.r.t. other datetimes within same `id` and same date. For `id`='a1' and date='2016-01-01', the `datetime_baseline`='2016-01-01 00:01:00.156'. So, at index=0, `timedelta` has value=0 because '2016-01-01 00:01:00.156' - `datetime_baseline`=0. Meanwhile, at index=1, `timedelta` has value=719 because '2016-01-01 12:00:00.425' - `datetime_baseline`=719 (minutes). At index=2, `id` is the same as before but date is now '2016-01-02', so a new baseline will be used: '2016-01-02 00:59:00.123'. `timedelta`='2016-01-02 00:59:00.123' - `datetime_baseline`=0. At index=3,  `timedelta`='2016-01-02 14:16:00.548' - `datetime_baseline`=797.

Although I see how the `timedelta` values should be calculated (`timedelta=datetime-datetime_baseline`), I don't know how to have the baseline values identified (i.e. how to generate `datetime_baseline` column). Please, let me know if you need any further explanation.

ps> the actual dataframe has +500 thousand rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['datetime_baseline'] = df.groupby(['id', df['datetime'].dt.date])["datetime"].transform('min')
df['timedelta'] = np.round((df['datetime'] - df['datetime_baseline']).dt.seconds / 60)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id                datetime       datetime_baseline  timedelta
0   a1 2016-01-01 00:01:00.156 2016-01-01 00:01:00.156        0.0
1   a1 2016-01-01 12:00:00.425 2016-01-01 00:01:00.156      719.0
2   a1 2016-01-02 00:59:00.123 2016-01-02 00:59:00.123        0.0
3   a1 2016-01-02 14:16:00.548 2016-01-02 00:59:00.123      797.0
4   a2 2016-01-01 12:00:00.147 2016-01-01 12:00:00.147        0.0
5   a2 2016-01-01 13:59:00.123 2016-01-01 12:00:00.147      119.0
6   a2 2016-01-02 08:01:00.147 2016-01-02 08:01:00.147        0.0
7   a2 2016-01-02 18:49:00.123 2016-01-02 08:01:00.147      648.0
8   a3 2016-02-01 12:00:00.147 2016-02-01 12:00:00.147        0.0
9   a3 2016-02-01 13:59:00.123 2016-02-01 12:00:00.147      119.0
10  a3 2016-02-02 08:01:00.147 2016-02-02 08:01:00.147        0.0
11  a3 2016-02-02 18:49:00.123 2016-02-02 08:01:00.147      648.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've met the following error from the first code line: "ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (418643, 23)". This dataframe has 418643 rows and 23 columns. I suspect there is something missing before .transform('min') which I believe is "[datetime]"

Comment: @NigelBlainey You've probably have more columns in your dataframe as in your example. Try `df.groupby(['id', df['datetime'].dt.date])["datetime"].transform('min')` (I've updated my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

With [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to make the *baseline* :

```
df["datetime_baseline"] = (df.groupby(["id", df["datetime"].dt.date])
                                              ["datetime"].transform("first"))
```

And [`dt.total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) to compute the *timedelta* :

```
df["timedelta"] = ((df["datetime"].sub(df["datetime_baseline"]))
                                .dt.total_seconds().div(60).round(0).astype(int))
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

    id                datetime       datetime_baseline  timedelta
0   a1 2016-01-01 00:01:00.156 2016-01-01 00:01:00.156          0
1   a1 2016-01-01 12:00:00.425 2016-01-01 00:01:00.156        719
2   a1 2016-01-02 00:59:00.123 2016-01-02 00:59:00.123          0
3   a1 2016-01-02 14:16:00.548 2016-01-02 00:59:00.123        797
4   a2 2016-01-01 12:00:00.147 2016-01-01 12:00:00.147          0
5   a2 2016-01-01 13:59:00.123 2016-01-01 12:00:00.147        119
6   a2 2016-01-02 08:01:00.147 2016-01-02 08:01:00.147          0
7   a2 2016-01-02 18:49:00.123 2016-01-02 08:01:00.147        648
8   a3 2016-02-01 12:00:00.147 2016-02-01 12:00:00.147          0
9   a3 2016-02-01 13:59:00.123 2016-02-01 12:00:00.147        119
10  a3 2016-02-02 08:01:00.147 2016-02-02 08:01:00.147          0
11  a3 2016-02-02 18:49:00.123 2016-02-02 08:01:00.147        648
```

Comment: Yes, your solution works pretty well. Thank you!